# Media Queries fails in iPad for my website

Tags: html, css, media-queries

My media queries does not seems to apply in ipad. Website is http://www.purplesale.com. In the last of the css i have applied media queries for ipad -

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
#mainContent, #container, #sidebar, #content, #footer, #betaSpacer {
    width: 765px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
// Other queries targeting ipad

}
/*End*/
```

Full CSS is here - http://www.purplesale.com/Css/main.css

viewport set in meta is -

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
```

please help in solving the problem.

Comment: what's the device width of 'an iPad'?

Comment: 768px  * 1024px is for all ipads

Answer (score 0):

If Ipad with retina display ( ipad 3 & 4 )

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) { /* STYLES GO HERE */}
```

Comment: what's the use of -webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2 is this necessary for ipad media queries to work?

Comment: As you mentioned in above post all 5 different iPads (iPads 1-5 and iPad mini) have the same resolution 768x1024 and it can be targeted with the same media query. but ipad 3 and 4 comes with retina display if you want media query specific to that devices we can use -webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2 for others -webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1

Comment: Now only i noticed the CSS you given, sometimes the issue may be with the ordering of media queries. please remove the other media queries and check in ipad